# ASP.NET Password and Confirmation in ClientSideEvents

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I have 2 ASPxTextBox, ASPxValidationSummary and ASPxButton 
In JS file there is OnPasswordValidation function 
But when i type a password then click Tab button the SetIsValid(false) 
on txt_password control doesn't work but it work on txt_ConfirmPassword

Why ?

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server" Password="true" AssociatedControlID="txt_password">
    <ClientSideEvents Validation="OnPasswordValidation" />
</dx:ASPxTextBox>

<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txt_ConfirmPassword" runat="server" Password="true" AssociatedControlID="txt_ConfirmPassword">
    <ClientSideEvents Validation="OnPasswordValidation" />
</dx:ASPxTextBox>

<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ClientInstanceName="btnSubmit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" AutoPostBack="False">
<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {onClickBtnSubmit();}"/>
</dx:ASPxButton>

function OnPasswordValidation(s, e) {
    var objpassword = GetObj('txt_password');
    var objConfirmPassword = GetObj('txt_ConfirmPassword');
    var password = aspxGetControlCollection().Get(objpassword.id);
    var ConfirmPassword = aspxGetControlCollection().Get(objConfirmPassword.id);

    if (password.GetValue() == null) {
        password.SetIsValid(false);
        ConfirmPassword.SetIsValid(false);
        return;
    }
    if (ConfirmPassword.GetValue() == null) {
        password.SetIsValid(false);
        ConfirmPassword.SetIsValid(false);
        return;
    }
    if (password.GetValue().length > 5 || ConfirmPassword.GetValue().length > 5) {
        if (password.GetValue() == ConfirmPassword.GetValue()) {
            password.SetIsValid(true);
            ConfirmPassword.SetIsValid(true);
        }
        else {
            password.SetIsValid(false);
            ConfirmPassword.SetIsValid(false);
            password.SetErrorText = "Password must equal with Confirm Password";
            ConfirmPassword.SetErrorText = "Password must equal with Confirm Password";
        }
    }
    else {
        ConfirmPassword.SetIsValid(false);
        password.SetIsValid(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a proper way to implement validation. This way `OnPasswordValidation` function is executed twice, once for every textbox.
Here is a ticket with sample project that should do what you need: 
   http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q233058.aspx

I advice you to read DevExpress controls [validation overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11111) in order to understand how to implement validation on devex controls.